# Работа с массивом в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

Создается массив в контроллере, инициализируется в методе Index.
После того, как я его проинициализировал , я попадаю в метод Points и работаю с ним, но у меня появляется ошибка NullReferenceException.

**Контроллер.**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private Club[] clubs;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        clubs = new Club[3];
        clubs[0] = new Club { Name = "Arsenal", Points = 3 };
        clubs[1] = new Club { Name = "Liverpool", Points = 2 };
        clubs[2] = new Club { Name = "Brighton", Points = 1 };

        return View(clubs);
    }

    //NullReferenceException
    public IActionResult Points()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clubs.Length; i++)
        {
            clubs[i].PointsAfterGame(3);
        }
        return View(clubs);
    }


    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

Как решить проблему?

upd..
Класс Club

```
public class Club
{

    private Random rnd = new Random();
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Points{ get; set; }

    public int PointsAfterGame(int gameCount)
    {
       return Points = rnd.Next(0, gameCount) * 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно после туда попадаете? Ну и вообще покажите описание этого `clubs` хотя бы.

Comment: Сначала попадаю в индекс, массив инициализируется. Дальше на вьюшке есть ссылка , которая указывает на метод Points - по нажатию на нее попадаю в новую вьюшку и там должен выводить новые данные. Добавил скрин описания класса Club в описании проблемы

Comment: @CrazyElf сейчас я Вам объясню то , что хочу сделать. Допустим , есть представление - на нем выводится список клубов и кнопка "Начать сезон". По нажатию срабатывает метод из класса , который устанавливает количество очков клубам.

Comment: Лучше добавляйте код в виде текста, а не скриншотов, иначе готовьтесь к тому, что ваш вопрос заминусуют. А так хотелось бы ещё увидеть где сам массив `clubs` описан и инициализирован. Может он у вас при каждом обращении к контроллеру инициализируется заново, например.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за совет. а на счет массива - массив clubs описан в классе HomeController. я так понимаю, я получил ответ на свой вопрос. видимо он заново инициализируется, как только я обращаюсь к контроллеру.

Comment: Ну вот попробуйте его в `Index()` собственно инициализировать, где у вас его элементам что-то присваивается. А оттуда где сейчас убрать инициализацию, оставить только описание типа. Не факт, что проблема именно в этом, но вполне может быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf попробовал сделать как Вы подсказали но не получилось. после инициализации, при нажатии на ссылку вызова метода Points - массив пуст.

Comment: Приведите весь нужный код в вопросе в виде текста. Сейчас мы гадаем на кофейной гуще. Я вообще плохо помню какой там workflow и сохраняются ли вообще переменные между обращениями к контроллеру. Может их куда-то в сессию нужно записывать. Почитайте какую-нибудь литературу, примеры, как правильно всё сделать.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил код. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: В общем, вам похоже надо "вручную" сохранять состояние переменных между обращениями к контроллеру: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482826/8324991

Comment: При вызове каждого метода создаётся новый экземпляр контроллера. Естественно, при вызове `Points()` массив оказывается неинициализированным.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. буду разбираться